# get info on all catholic churches in Europe

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

i 'm looking to get info on all catholic churches in Europe. Specifically, I'd love to get:

their address
Denomination
Active/Not
Contact Info (website, email, phone)
and any other info I can get.

well we ve got several approaches:

- use overpass-tubro.eu;
- we can get a list of all "places of worship" by downloading bulk osm files from geofabrik.de and then using use osmfilter or osmosis to select only certain tags, for example: wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity=place_of_worship

> to use the Open StreetMap data with Nominatom for a base file. This
> should get the #1 and then we can get #2 just by text mining their
> titles. For #3 I believe the closest you'll get is just to use the
> most recent available data. For #4 I think we'd need to do original
> data scraping from the Internet - at least to get their websites (I'm
> not sure on this one, actually).

btw: see a List of Catholic dioceses (structured view)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Catholic_dioceses_(structured_view)#Episcopal_Conference_of_France

> As of May 31, 2018, the Catholic Church in its entirety comprises
> 3,160 ecclesiastical jurisdictions, including over 645 archdioceses
> and 2,236 dioceses,  as well as apostolic vicariates, apostolic
> exarchates, apostolic administrations, apostolic prefectures, military
> ordinariates, personal ordinariates,  personal prelatures, territorial
> prelatures, territorial abbacies and missions sui juris around the
> world.

do you know more ways to go ahead and find the appropiate dataset

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this ?  I google it and try to see if there's any and it came up...

https://catholic-geo-hub-cgisc.hub.arcgis.com/pages/a-globalchurch